# Selecting elements with similar class

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```html
<div class="price">
    <del><span class="amount">100</span></del>
    <ins><span class="amount">1000</span></ins>
</div>

<div class="price">
    <span class="amount">1000</span>
</div>
```

And I want to color only the spans with the class `amount` in them. But some of them are wrapped in the `<ins>` tag, and some are not. How to do that? I tried with pseudoselectors but no luck.

#### Solution

```css
.price ins .amount, 
.price > .amount{
    color: red;
}
```

EDIT (28.04.2021.)

I've edited this for more clarity. Back in 2014 I knew nothing about CSS, funny to see this from today's perspective

Comment: Do these numbers change or stay constant?

Comment: I wasn't clear enough, the content is irrelevant. It's the elements I'm targeting.

Comment: But which element? There are three elements with class `amount`

Comment: And that's the problem XD I need the second `ammount` class, wrapped in `<ins>` for which the css is just `.price ins .amount`, and I need the second `amount`. Should the second one be `.price>.amount`?

Comment: Ok, well have you tried any of these things?

Comment: The first one I have, second not.

Comment: Ok, I have now, and that works :D Thanks xD

Answer (score 2):

You can't use CSS to evaluate the content of elements. You would need to use javascript.

You could use this javascript to do it.

```
var amountEls = document.getElementsByClassName('amount');

for (var i = 0; i < amountEls.length; i++) {
    var amount = amountEls[i];
    if (amount.innerHTML.indexOf('1000') > -1) {
        amount.style.background = 'yellow';
    }
}
```

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0z737g3s/) - if you wanted the text to change color rather than the background just change `background` to `color`.

**EDIT** - If the positions of these elements are *always* static and you're *not* targeting the numbers - just the second and third `.amount` 'span's - then you can use:

```
.price ins .amount,
.price + .price .amount {
    background: yellow;
}
```

The `+` operator is the adjacent sibling selector and in this instance selects any `.price .amount` that is preceded by a `.price`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery (or simple javascript) an color it on load, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function({
    $(".amount").each(function(){
        if(parseInt($(this).html()) >= 1000){
            $(this).css('color', 'green');
        }
    });
}));
```

Comment: I made myself unclear. The content isn't the problem. I don't care about the content :D I just need to target those two classes. I could do that with jquery as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**CSS:**

```
.price span.amount{color:green;}
.price del span.amount{color:initial;}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/334/

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="price">
    <del><span class="amount">100</span></del>
    <ins><span class="amount hlt_txt">1000</span></ins>
</div>
<div class="price">
    <span class="amount hlt_txt">1000</span>
</div>
```

and in ur CSS

```
    .hlt_txt{color:green;}
```

Comment: I don't get how this would help :S

Comment: I can't add classes ;) They are fixed, sadly.